# Capture Image from Camera and Display in Same Activity. -Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I have been searching for how to do this. I am able to access my camera and gallery to upload images to my database. But this is what i want to do, i want to take the picture in my activity, crop and add text in the same activity, and display the photos in thumbnail in the same activity. 
(similar to that of WhatsApp).

Lots of tutorials are displaying the imageview and textview but do not display the images on the same activity.
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lots of tutorials are displaying the imageview and textview but do not display the images on the same activity. How do i achieve this?

You can put the Preview in the layout of your activity, and compress and show the image after taking picture(Steps below):

1. Create a Preview class for Camera Preview:

   ```
   public class Preview : SurfaceView, ISurfaceHolderCallback
   {
       private Android.Hardware.Camera mCamera;

       public Preview(Context context, Android.Hardware.Camera camera):base(context)
       {
           mCamera = camera;
           Holder.AddCallback(this);
           // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
           Holder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);
       }
       public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
       {
           // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
           // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

           if (Holder.Surface == null)
           {
               // preview surface does not exist
               return;
           }

           // stop preview before making changes
           try
           {
               mCamera.StopPreview();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
           }

           // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
           // reformatting changes here

           // start preview with new settings
           try
           {
               mCamera.SetPreviewDisplay(Holder);
               mCamera.StartPreview();

           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               //Deal with exception
           }
       }

       public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
       {
          // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
           try
           {
               mCamera.SetPreviewDisplay(Holder);
               mCamera.StartPreview();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
               e.PrintStackTrace();
           }
       }

       public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
       {
           // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
       }

   }
   ```
2. Prepare the Layout to hold the Camera Preview  and your Image:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="250dp">
       <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     </LinearLayout>
     <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgResult"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
     <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnClick"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Click Me"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Create `Camera` and `Preview` in Activity and register for taking picture's callback:

   ```
   public class MainActivity : Activity,IPictureCallback
   {
       bool isCameraOpened;
       Preview mPreview;
       Android.Hardware.Camera mCamera;
       Button btnClick;
       FrameLayout camera_preview;
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           base.OnCreate(bundle);

           // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
           SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
           btnClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClick);
           camera_preview = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.camera_preview);
           mCamera = GetCameraInstance();
           mCamera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
           mPreview = new Preview(this, mCamera);
           camera_preview.AddView(mPreview);
           btnClick.Click += BtnClick_Click;
       }

       private bool CheckCameraHardware()
       {
           if (this.PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureCamera))
           {
               return true;
           } else
           {
               return false;
           }

       }

   private void BtnClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       mCamera.TakePicture(null, null, this);
   }

       private Android.Hardware.Camera GetCameraInstance()
       {
           Android.Hardware.Camera c=null;
           try
           {
               c = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();
           }
           catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
           {

           }

           return c;
       }

       public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
       {
           Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
           Bitmap resizedBitmap=Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
           FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgResult).SetImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
           //restart the preview
           if (mCamera != null)
           {
               mCamera.StartPreview();
           }

       }
   }
   ```

For detailed use of Camera API, you can refer to [Camera API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#considerations).

Notes: Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` and
  `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HashMap for storing the 'text' as the key & 'image path' as its value. Make its instance on Application class.

You can use that HashMap on onActivityResult() method.

Comment: can you be a little clearer please? How is that going to function i mean